# Swift: Print decimal precision of division

Tags: swift, variables

I'm trying print the result of division for example:

```
let division = (4/6)
print(division)
```

In this case the print out is 0.

How can I print the numeric value of the division without losing the numeric value. I mean without casting the output to string.

Answer (score 9):

You are performing integer division. You need to perform floating point division.

In your code, `division` is an `Int` value. `4 / 6` is zero in integer division.

You need:

```
let division = 4.0/6.0
print(division)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ans = Double(no1)/Double(no2)
    return ans
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value should be correct, then try as

```
let division = Float(v1) / Float(v2)
print(division)
```