# Divide two numbers and return fraction in swift

Tags: ios, swift, math, division

I know this is a simple question, but i would like to get a result like this.

3/6 = 0.500000

Divide two numbers and return quotient and reminder in a single variable, how can i achieve above in swift ?

Comment: Give a proper example please with both quotient and reminder

Comment: Do you mean something like `print("\(x)/\(y) = \(Double(x)/Double(y))")`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson This is the case 3/6 = 0.500000 , which part is unclear ?

if i divide 3 with 6 , i would like to capture its value as 0.500000.

Comment: What is unclear is that you say you want to "return quotient _and_ reminder" and that is not what you have in your example.

Comment: So this is your actual problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40579550/swift-print-decimal-precision-of-division.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get the quotient and remainder of a division, you can use the `quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy:)` function.

```
3.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: 6) // (quotient 0, remainder 3)
```

If you want to get the floating point result of a division, use the `/` operator on two floating point numbers.

Either do

```
let result = 3.0 / 6.0 // 0.5
```

or if your integers are coming from variables, do

```
let result = Double(3.0) / Double(6.0) // 0.5
```

Comment: I want the op like - 0.500000 , the above code op is (quotient: 0, remainder: 3).

Comment: @FaizalMalik: Then clarify your question. `0` and `3` *are* quotient and remainder of that integer division.

Comment: @MartinR my question description is pretty clear , i want an output like 3/6 = 0.500000.

Comment: @FaizalMalik your question description is contradicting itself actually. You can get the floating point result of division by simply doing `let divided = 3.0/6.0` or `let divided = Double(3)/Double(6)`. The quotient and remainder are given using the code in my question.

Comment: let divided = Double(3)/Double(6) == 0.5 , how can i get the result as 0.500000.

Comment: @FaizalMalik `let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 6
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 1
if let value = Double(3)/Double(6) as? NSNumber {
   let string = formatter.string(from: value)
}`

Comment: Thank you @DávidPásztor and Joakim